# How to inherite stylesheet from QApplication in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I am using external and universal stylesheet through reading qss file like below

```
QFile File("../Stylesheet.qss");
File.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString StyleSheet = QLatin1String(File.readAll());
pApp->setStyleSheet(StyleSheet);
```

**stylesheet.qss is good and working**

**Problem**
I have a widget which initialize with no parent. like

```
WorkspaceWindow::WorkspaceWindow(WorkspaceWindow* pWorkspaceWindow)
    : QWidget()
{}
```

because of this stylesheet is not applying on WorkspaceWindow & its children widget.

**My Approach**
I created a dummy class which inherits from QWidget and set stylesheet on this class at constructor.

```
class PrimaryWidget:public QWidget;

PrimaryWidget::PrimaryWidget()
{
    QFile File("../Stylesheet.qss");
    File.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString StyleSheet = QLatin1String(File.readAll());
    setStyleSheet(StyleSheet);
}

static PrimaryWidget& get()
{
     static PrimaryWidget obj;
     return obj;
}
```

now I am using WorkspaceWindow as

```
WorkspaceWindow::WorkspaceWindow(WorkspaceWindow* pWorkspaceWindow)
    : QWidget(&PrimaryWidget::get())
{}
```

now It working fine.

**Question**
How can avoid this scenario ? can I use QApplication object to initialize stylesheet for orphan objects (like WorkspaceWindow) ? or make WorkspaceWindow child of QApplication (kind of) ?

Comment: You could create class `StylelessWidget`, which does `setStyleSheet(QString())` in contructor, and inherit from it or make it parent.

Comment: Have you tried `setStyle(qApp->style())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dummy widget as parent for the soul purpose of setting a style sheet just doesn't feel right.

I would change your code to:

```
namespace myApp
{
    QString styleSheet()
    {
        QFile file("../Stylesheet.qss");
        file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
        const QString styleSheet = QLatin1String(File.readAll());
        return styleSheet;
    }
}
```

And in the constructor of your widget simply:

```
WorkspaceWindow::WorkspaceWindow(WorkspaceWindow* pWorkspaceWindow, QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
    if (parent == Q_NULLPTR) {
        setStyleSheet(myApp::styleSheet());
    }
}
```